# To access views and filters of each view (profile) of my Google Analytic account

Tags: r, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I wish to access to  views and the filters in each view of my Google Analytic account. Is there any reason that I cannot access them together? I can extract information about view and filters separately

I am now using R package (RGA) and 
have

```
list_profiles()
```

and

```
list_filters()
```

but how can I see the views and also the filters of each view?

Comment: [Profile Filter Links reference docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/profileFilterLinks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filters are account based not view based really.   I cant help with R but you should be able to do it the API supports it.

[Account Summaries list](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accountSummaries/list) will give you a list of all of the accounts, properties and views that the current authenticated user has access to

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accountSummaries
```

if you loop though each of the accounts then run:

[Filters: list](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/filters/list) to get a list of each of the filters back for that account.

GET https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/accountId/filters

Hope this helps in the mean time I will ping someone who knows R for you